# WCF - Publisher-Subscriber - Subscription Problem

Tags: wcf, publish-subscribe

### Publisher Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IPublisherInterface
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
        void Publish(MessageClass e, string topicName);

    }
```

### Subscriber Interface

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IPublisherInterface))]
    public interface ISubscriberInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Subscribe(string topicName);

        [OperationContract]
        void UnSubscribe(string topicName);
    }
```

### Subscriber Program

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DuplexChannelFactory<ISubscriberInterface> namedPipeFactory =
               new DuplexChannelFactory<ISubscriberInterface>(
                    new InstanceContext(new PublisherService()),
                  new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                  new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/Sub"));

            ISubscriberInterface pipeProxy = namedPipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            pipeProxy.Subscribe("name");

            //SubscriberForm f = new SubscriberForm(pipeProxy);
            //f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting this message?

```
The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/ISubscriberInterface/Subscribe' cannot be
 processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. 
This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and 
receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that
 sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security 
requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)."
```

### This is my Host

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost _publisherServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PublisherService), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/") });
            _publisherServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(IPublisherInterface),
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    "Pub");
            _publisherServiceHost.Open();

            ServiceHost _subscriberServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PublisherService), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/") });
            _subscriberServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(IPublisherInterface),
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    "Sub");
            _subscriberServiceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Server is Running.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, your problem is here:

```
_subscriberServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IPublisherInterface),
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                "Sub");
```

The Subscriber service host is created using **IPublisherInterface** contract, which is wrong. It should be **ISubscriberInterface** instead

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure with the second host opening? Shouldn't it be:

```
    ServiceHost _subscriberServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SubscriberService), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/sub") });
    _subscriberServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(ISubscriberInterface),
            new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
            "Sub");
    _subscriberServiceHost.Open();
```

I'm guessing the names, but I guess that probably the name you given to your ISubscriberInterface implementation.